# Nested html table is not loaded in document

Tags: html, excel, vba

When a button is clicked on a page using vba code, html table is loaded in the same page, but unable to retrieve the table information using vba code. When I refresh the page by manually pressing "Enter Key" in keyboad, I can able to get the table information using vba code. Please assist me how to get the nested table information from the page automatically using vba code. Kindly let me know if additional information is required.

**VBA Immediate Window**

```
<tr>
                        <td width="49%">


                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                        </td>
                </tr> </tbody></table>
            </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

**VBA Code**

```
Set btn = htmldoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnList")
btn.Click

Sleep (3000)

'waitForLoad ie
Set mybrowser = Nothing
Set mybrowser = FindWindow("rasp/CaseDetails.aspx")
Set htmldoc = mybrowser.Document

Debug.Print (htmldoc.body.innerHTML)
```

**HTML Code**

```
<tr>
                    <td width="49%">

                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" align="Right" rules="cols" border="1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdData" style="width:100%;text-decoration:none;height:11px;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-size:10px;font-family:Verdana;color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:None;border-color:#DEDFDE;background-color:White;border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr style="color:White;background-color:#6B696B;font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;height:11px;width:30px;">
    <td>Caseno</td><td>CaseDate</td><td>Status</td><td>Referenceno</td><td>Custname</td><td>MobileNo</td><td>Serialno</td><td>Brand</td><td>Model</td><td>ModelDesc</td><td>Popdate</td><td>SympCode1</td><td>SympCode2</td><td>SympCode3</td>
</tr><tr valign="top" style="background-color:#F7F7DE;font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;height:16px;width:30px;">
    <td><a href = frmView.aspx?jokey=3146288 target = _blank>0003146288</a></td><td>02/27/2019</td><td>Closed</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>MUHAMMAD AHAMED</td><td>0096599720991</td><td>VNF3D18318</td><td>HPIPGCONS</td><td>G3Q35A</td><td>HP LaserJet Pro M102w Prntr</td><td>06/09/2018</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr><tr valign="top" style="background-color:White;font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;height:16px;width:30px;">
    <td><a href = frmView.aspx?jokey=3146300 target = _blank>0003146300</a></td><td>02/27/2019</td><td>Closed</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>BURHAN TECHNOLOGY COMPUTER CO</td><td>0096598545714</td><td>CN88Q4R0C0</td><td>HPIPGCONS</td><td>G1X85A</td><td>HP Officejet 7612 WF e-All-in-</td><td>09/27/2018</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr><tr valign="top" style="background-color:#F7F7DE;font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;height:16px;width:30px;">
    <td><a href = frmView.aspx?jokey=3146378 target = _blank>0003146378</a></td><td>02/27/2019</td><td>Waiting for stock</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>LEAFIN INTERNATIONAL</td><td>0096550987136</td><td>U310C5BZ</td><td>Lenovo</td><td>65BA</td><td>LENOVO LI2054A Wide LCD Mon</td><td>01/09/2019</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr><tr valign="top" style="background-color:White;font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;height:16px;width:30px;">
    <td><a href = frmView.aspx?jokey=3146446 target = _blank>0003146446</a></td><td>02/27/2019</td><td>Closed</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>MOHAMMED IQBAL</td><td>0096597217552</td><td>VNBNKDJFF5</td><td>HPIPGCONS</td><td>T6B82A</td><td>HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M281</td><td>12/18/2017</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr><tr valign="top" style="background-color:#F7F7DE;font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;height:16px;width:30px;">
    <td><a href = frmView.aspx?jokey=3146572 target = _blank>0003146572</a></td><td>02/28/2019</td><td>Waiting for stock</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>CORE COME INTERNATIONAL</td><td>0096599143374</td><td>MP1EDCW0</td><td>Lenovo</td><td>IDEAPAD V330-14IKB</td><td>LENOVO V330-14IKB</td><td>10/17/2018</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr><tr valign="top" style="background-color:White;font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;height:16px;width:30px;">
    <td><a href = frmView.aspx?jokey=3146651 target = _blank>0003146651</a></td><td>02/28/2019</td><td>Closed</td><td>DOA</td><td>EUREKA HAWALLY</td><td>0096566212648</td><td>MP1D8K4Y</td><td>Lenovo</td><td>IDEAPAD 520-14IKB</td><td>LENOVO YOGA 520-14IKB</td><td>02/27/2019</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr><tr valign="top" style="background-color:#F7F7DE;font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;height:16px;width:30px;">
    <td><a href = frmView.aspx?jokey=3146901 target = _blank>0003146901</a></td><td>02/28/2019</td><td>Closed</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>SAKR ATTAI ZEDAIN</td><td>0096569335053</td><td>CN84H2G0Q2</td><td>HPIPGCONS</td><td>Z4B53A</td><td>HP Ink Tank WL 415 AiO Printer</td><td>08/19/2018</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr><tr valign="top" style="background-color:White;font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;height:16px;width:30px;">
```

Comment: *Set btn = htmldoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnList")
btn.Click*   Does this element indeed have a click handler?

Comment: @peakpeak: Dear peakpeak, Set btn = htmldoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnList") btn.click .  when btn.click  command executed, page will be refreshed and table will be displayed in the same page.At this moment I am not able to get displayed table information using document property of Internet explorer( ie.document ). please let me know if any additional information is required. Thanks for assisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been resolved. I put my code waiting until document is fully loaded. After document is fully loaded, I could access table. Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could post the URL.

The html code you've posted, where did you copy it from?

Keep in mind that when you `right-click` on the page and `View Page Source Code`, you could get a different result from the one you'll get by `Inspect Element`.

I can only assume that, what's happening in your case is that, your code returns the HTML file that is delivered to your browser before any DOM manipulation takes place.

In other words, the contents of the table you are interested in, are populated by a script and your code downloads the HTML, before this script takes effect onto it.

That's the equivalent of `View Page Source Code`. That could explain why the table you get is empty.

In any case, you should learn how to work with HTTP requests, to get the data you need instead of using IE. There are many posts on how to do that and it will make your life a lot easier.

My suggestion is, go to that site, open your browser's web developer tools and check the network traffic (`ctrl+Shift+E` if you're using firefox) when you press that button.

Find which request's response contains the data you're interested in and work from there.

Comment: @ Stavros Jon: Thanks for your wonderful explanation. Url: http://online.redingtongulf.com/servicemea/rasp/Login.aspx,  username:EGF-KUW, Password:init123, navigation: login->reports->click view case details ->click list -> Table will be listed.  I would like to get the table details in my code using (ie.document), after the list button is clicked. But I am not getting the table details, instead I am getting empty as mentioned above  VBA Immediate Window.  Please assist me to get the table details. Kindly let me know if any additional information is required.